# Canvas -- save final image after using destination-atop

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am using canvas `drawImage()` twice. One is a background image, and the other is some kind of 'mask' used to get the wanted image from the background.

The resulting image is the part of the background that's behind the overlay. I want to save that part of the image. Here's an example where I get the Hulk's face -- I want to create an image out of that face and save it on my server. Saving this image as is (right-click save image as) takes the full size of the canvas, and not just the wanted face.

http://jsfiddle.net/s248a76w/

HTML looks like:

`<canvas id="canvas" width="900" height="500"></canvas>`

JS:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
if (canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    //Load the images to be blended
    var userPic = new Image;
    userPic.src = "http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20090320033607/marvelmovies/images/5/5e/The-hulk-2003.jpg";
    var maskTemplate = new Image;
    maskTemplate.src = "http://www.botaiusti.com/img/1.svg";

    //Set the globalCompositeOperation to lighter
    // ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";

    //Draw the source image
    userPic.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(userPic, 100, 00);
    }


    //Draw the destination image
    maskTemplate.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(maskTemplate, 340, 70);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're lucky to have the background image loaded first, there is probably no guaranty on that. Have you tried to size your canvas at the size of the final image, instead of 900x500 ?

Comment: Thanks -- i put the overlaid image in the background's onload callback. I think I could dynamically resize the canvas at the end. Do you have any suggestion how I could have the image not in a rectangle shape (I'd need just the face image).

Comment: Resizing a canvas usually clear its content, so size it first, then draw your images with [drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawImage()) (use the one with several arguments)

Comment: So I should draw an image (strokes?) around the Hulk's face in my example, then take the content inside that image and save it? I don't know how to get that done yet, but if that's a way to go I'll do it.

Comment: Not exactly what I meant, first size your canvas at the size of the final image (```canvas.width=111111;canvas.height=111111;```), then draw inside. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/s248a76w/1/